# Are there guidelines for mid-sentence code blocks and bulleted lists

Tags: writing-style, technical

#### Question

Are there guidelines for the placement of nonstandard typography in the middle of a sentence?

I'm working on a blog that will have multiple authors.  Should we bother with style consistency across authors?  If so, is there an authority I can reference for this type of thing?

I'm referring to examples like the ones in the section below.

#### Examples

Don't require ssh key authentication unless you've checked that

- the permissions on your keys are correct, and
- you won't be locked out once the setting takes effect.

---

You can list the running processes with `ps aux`

---

First,

```
$ git add <the file you changed>
$ git commit
```

and then describe your changes in the editor.  Saving the buffer will create the commit.

---

Comment: This depends on the specific site and what features it supports.  Eg, here, when I need to quote a search string for Google, I use `back quotes` -- the formatting intended for code.

Comment: We're developers, so it supports whatever we decide to make it support.  The style hiccups don't tend to happen around custom functionality though, usually it's just the normal markdown things: https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Comment: Consistency in formatting signals professionalism. That mark gives your readers confidence they're in good hands. And bullets do not need *and* to connect and a period to end. If you wanted to introduce choices, you can start the second bullet with **Or**.

Comment: @YosefBaskin good points about professionalism, thanks.  I also dislike the *and*, but that's what the author did.  The question is whether to disallow it, and how to go about doing so.